# Does openapi support default values for complex types?

Tags: swagger-2.0, openapi

I couldn't find an example in OpenAPI spec  (either v2.x or 3.x) in https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md that defines a `default` for a complex (non-primitive) type. Is there a place where it states that it is supported or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `default` can be used with both primitive and complex types. `default` is an attribute of the [Schema Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#schema-object), and Schema Object is used to define both primitive and complex data types.

While not stated explicitly, this is implied from the descriptions of the Schema Object and the `default` attribute:

> The Schema Object allows the definition of input and output data types. These types can be objects, but also primitives and arrays.
>
> ...
>
> - `default` - The default value represents what would be assumed by the consumer of the input as the value of the schema if one is not provided.